# Identify Memory Corruption

Tags: c++, memory

I'm having trouble identifying a possible source of memory corruption in the following code. Is it due to the fact that I don't call the `free()` function on `char *stringToAdd`?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define MAX 1024

char* add_strings(char *stringOne, char *stringTwo);

int main() {
    char s = 'x';
    char *stringOne = &s;
    char *stringTwo = new char[1025]();
    char *final = add_strings(stringOne, stringTwo);
    return 0;
}

char* add_strings(char *stringOne, char *stringTwo) {
    unsigned int lengthOfStringOne = strlen(stringOne);
    unsigned int lengthOfStringTwo = strlen(stringTwo);
    cout << lengthOfStringOne << endl;
    cout << lengthOfStringTwo << endl;

    char *stringToAdd = lengthOfStringOne < lengthOfStringTwo ? stringOne : stringTwo;
    unsigned int lengthOfAdd = lengthOfStringOne < lengthOfStringTwo ? lengthOfStringOne : lengthOfStringTwo;

    char *final = static_cast<char*>(calloc(MAX, sizeof(char)));
    unsigned int avgLengthOfStrings = (lengthOfStringOne + lengthOfStringTwo) / 2;
    if (avgLengthOfStrings < MAX) {
        strncat(final, stringToAdd, lengthOfAdd);
        printf("DONE\n");
    } else {
        printf("Average length of both input strings exceeds liimit.\n");
        free(final);
        return NULL;
    }
    return final;
}
```

Comment: This is C++ code. Please don't tag it as C.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `new[]` instead of C's `malloc()` and `calloc()` if you must do allocations. Use `std::string` instead of C strings. Use `std::vector` instead of regular C arrays. Use `nullptr` instead of C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: `char *stringOne = &s;` isn't pointing to a (null terminated) string - just a single `char`. So you can't apply `strlen()` to in the function it is passed to.

Comment: It's worth noting that all of this code goes away if you use C++ effectively. `std::string x = "a"; std::string y = "b"; std::string z = a + b;`.

Comment: This could also be reduced to C-style code that's basically `calloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1, sizeof(char))` and then `strncpy()` and `strncat()`. **DO NOT** forget the byte required for the NUL terminator. This off-by-one bug can cause huge problems. You define `MAX` but it's entirely pointless, you know the lengths of the strings you're adding. You also test incorrectly that the average(??) is less than the maximum, when it should be that the *sum* is.

Comment: Not calling `free()` doesn't lead to crashes, it leads to memory leaks, which are a whole other sort of problem.

Comment: valgrind says: ==520079== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==520079==    at 0x483DB98: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:459)
==520079==    by 0x40124E: add_strings(char*, char*) (delme.cpp:22)
==520079==    by 0x401227: main (delme.cpp:17)